# HTTP POST request vs WebSockets

Tags: node.js, express, http, post, socket.io

I recently started using Socket.io in my NodeJS app with express where I use post request to handle form submission and data. Why isn't Socket.io used to do the same thing with only get requests?

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets and Socket.io are mostly used if data has to be transmitted in "real time". For example the server needs to push some small piece of data to the clients. This avoids server load which would be caused by polling from the clients.

Therefore, WebSockets are useful in applications where the data needs to be pushed to the clients, e.g. a chat system. One important thing is that it requires a persistent connection between the server and the client.